# Is it possible to implement kvm/qemu VM guests and host connected through shared memory to collect and cache data between them

Tags: virtual-machine, cache, shared-memory

**The configuration:**

- host: Ubuntu:20.04 OS
- guest: Ubuntu20.04 OS
- The two files use the 9p file system for interworking.

**The mount command is as follows,**

```shell
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio tmp_shared /mnt -oversion=9p2000.l
```

**The current progress is as follows:**

- The `mmap` function in C language is used to map the memory of the same file through the 9p file system.
- At present, host can write to the memory of the file, but guest cannot read the change in real time.
- Host side: `write.c` (this code is to modify the file memory)

  ```C
  #include <sys/mman.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #define _GBU_SOURCE
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  #define FILE_PATH "/tmp/shared/test.txt" //file path

  int main()
  {
      int fd;
      struct stat fa;
      char *mapped;

      // open
      if ((fd = open(FILE_PATH, O_CREAT | O_RDWR)) < 0){
          perror("open");
          exit(1);
      }

      // attr
      if ((fstat(fd, &fa)) == -1){
          perror("fstat");
          exit(1);
      }

      // map
      if ((mapped = (char *)mmap(NULL, fa.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == (void *)-1){
          perror("mmap");
          exit(1);
      }

      // close
      close(fd);

      printf("before :\n%s\n", mapped);

      mapped[3] = 'P';

      printf("\nafter:\n%s\n", mapped);


      if (munmap(mapped, fa.st_size) == -1)
      {
          perror("munmap");
          exit(1);
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Guest side: `read.c` (this code is to keep reading the file)

  ```C
  #include <sys/mman.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <error.h>

  #define FILE_PATH "/mnt/test.txt" // file path

  int main()
  {
      int fd;
      struct stat fa;
      char *mapped;

      // open
      if ((fd = open(FILE_PATH, O_RDWR)) < 0)
      {
          perror("open");
          exit(1);
      }

      // attr
      if ((fstat(fd, &fa)) == -1)
      {
          perror("fstat");
          exit(1);
      }

      // map
      if ((mapped = (char *)mmap(NULL, fa.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == (void *)-1)
      {
          perror("mmap");
          exit(1);
      }

      // close
      close(fd);

      // read
      while (1)
      {
          printf("%s\n", mapped);
          sleep(2);
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```